# In PHP, how can I get any string after the domain to be a php variable? Ex: me.com/FOO, me.com/VAR3

Tags: php, redirect

so my index.php can be this:

```
<?php
      $restOfURL = ''; //idk how to get this
      print $restOfURL; //this should print 'FOO', 'VAR3', or any string after the domain.
 ?>
```

Comment: Yes. None of the folders exist.. they can be anything, so I can't use the server variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, as everybody has pointed out, can tell you what the URL looks like, but it doesn't really work the way you want it unless you have a way to point requests for `me.com/VALUE1` and `me.com/VALUE2` to the script that will do the processing. (Otherwise your server will return a 404 error unless you have a script for each value you want, in which case the script already knows the value...)

Assuming you're using apache, you want to use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html). You'll have to install and enable the module and then add some [directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) to your .htaccess, httpd.conf or virtual host config. This allows you make a request for `me.com/XXX` map internally to `me.com/index.php?var=XXX`, so you can read the value from `$_GET['var']`.

Comment: haha, it took me 18 minutes to write my response. Good pickup

Answer (score 4):

You want to use,

```
<?php
    $restOfURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    // If you want to remove the slash at the beginning you can use ltrim()
    $restOfURL = ltrim($restOfURL, "/");
?>
```

You can find more of the predefined server variables in the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

**Update**
Based on your comment to the question, I guess you're using something like mod_rewrite to rewrite the FOO, etc and route everything to just one file (index.php). In that case I would expect the rest of the URL to already be passed to the index.php file. However, if not, you can use mod_rewrite to pass the rest of the URL as a GET variable, and then just use that GET variable in your index.php file.

So if you enable [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and then add something like this to your `.htaccess` file,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then the rest of the URL will be available to you in your index.php file from the `$_GET['url']` variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
$var = ltrim( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/' )
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: hmm the only file that exists in the server is index.php. No folders or any other files exist..

Answer (score 1):

Just by looking at the examples, i think you are looking for the apache mod_rewrite.
You can apply a RewriteRule via an htaccess file, for example:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([\w]+)$ /checkin.php?string=$1 [L]
```

For example this url http://foo.com/aka2 will be process by checkin.php script and will have "aka2" passed as $_GET['string'].

Make no mistake, the URL will still be visible in the browser as http://foo.com/aka2 but the server will actually process http://foo.com/checkin.php?string=aka

[mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

Comment: hmm the only file that exists in the server is index.php. No folders or any other files exist..

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with all the fancy mod_rewrite/query_string business? There's already `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` available for just such data.